# PHP стриминг большого аудиофайла

Tags: php, передача-данных, аудио

Ситуация такая: есть бесконечно выполняющийся *php*-скрипт, генерирующий большой аудиофайл путём склейки файлов из указанной папки (разумеется, итоговый размер неизвестен) и отдающий клиенту получающийся файл с заголовком *content-type: audio/mpeg*.

Проблема: хостинг имеет ограничение на размер скачиваемого пользователем файла. Доступа к *nginx/php.ini* и т. д. нет. Обращаюсь к комьюнити с вопросом: можно ли как-то поток сегментировать на части, к примеру, по 256 кб и отправлять клиенту по кускам? И если да, то попрошу поделиться способом.

P. S. Пробовал методом chunk download. Файл-то всё равно идёт клиенту монолитно и всё равно упирается в ограничение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для правильной работы chunk download необходим заголовок:

```
header("Accept-Ranges:bytes");
```

Если и это вдруг не помогло, в ход идут запрещённые приёмы - сбрасывать страницу каждые XXX секунд.

```
header("Refresh:XXX");
```